# Validation message in CPQ

Tags: validation, cpq, steelbrick

I am getting a validation message on SFDC CPQ Quote edit Line , 
"Addon Fulfillment start dates must be equal to or after Parent Fullfilment start dates."

But could not able to find it out from which object this is coming. In fact there is no such message we have set.

Answer (score 0):

This could either be coming from Salesforce Validation Rules or CPQ's Product Rules. My guess here is that it's from a Product Rule

Comment: You are right .This is product Rule.